# Every time I press the number for the player selection it repeats "computer chose __" and doesn't display the result. What am I doing wrong here?

Tags: c#

/* Simple rock paper scissors game that asks the user if they'd like to play, 
   displays the computer choice, and displays the result (like a judge), no 
   advanced techniques. I also needed the game to loop again if the user says 
   yes to playing again. I am very very new to programming in general and just
   having a hard time nailing down the basics.*/

```
using System;

class RockPaperScissors
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.Write("Do you want to play rock, paper, scissors? ");
        string playerChoice = Console.ReadLine();
        playerChoice = playerChoice.ToUpper();


        Random r = new Random();
        int computerChoice = r.Next(1, 4);

        do
        {

            if (computerChoice == 1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Computer chose Rock");
                Console.Write("Player choice: type 1, 2, or 3 (1=rock 2=paper 
                3=scissors): ");
                Console.ReadKey();

            //beginning of switch
            switch (playerChoice)
                {
                    case "1":
                        Console.WriteLine("/nIt is a tie!");
                        break;
                    case "2":
                        Console.WriteLine("/nYou win! Paper covers rock!");
                        break;
                    case "3":
                        Console.WriteLine("/nComputer wins! Rock crushes 
                        scissors!");
                        break;
                }//end of switch
            }

            else if (computerChoice == 2)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Computer chose paper");
                Console.Write("Player choice: type 1, 2, or 3 (1=rock 2=paper 
                3=scissors): ");
                Console.ReadKey();

            //beginning of switch
            switch (playerChoice)
                {
                    case "1":
                        Console.WriteLine("/nComputer wins! Paper covers 
                        rock!");
                        break;
                    case "2":
                        Console.WriteLine("/nIt is a tie!");
                        break;
                    case "3":
                        Console.WriteLine("/nYou win! Scissors cuts paper!");
                        break;
                } //end of switch
            }

            else if (computerChoice == 3)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Computer chose scissors");
                Console.Write("Player choice: type 1, 2, or 3 (1=rock 2=paper 
                3=scissors): ");
                Console.ReadKey();

            //beginning of switch
            switch (playerChoice)
                {
                    case "1":
                        Console.WriteLine("/nYou win! Rock crushes scissors!");
                        break;
                    case "2":
                        Console.WriteLine("/nComputer wins! Scissors cuts 
                        paper!");
                        break;
                    case "3":
                        Console.WriteLine("/nIt is a tie!");
                        break;
                } //end of switch

            }

        } while (playerChoice == "YES");
    }
}
```

Comment: This is actually a great opportunity for you to start learning your most valuable tool as a programmer... the debugger.  In Visual Studio you can set a "break point" on any line of code and then when you run in debug mode the running will "pause" on that line.  You can use the debug options to step through the code line by line, observe the runtime values and behavior, etc.  This will help you find specifically where the program first does something you don't expect it to.  Once you have that information, we can help you understand why it's doing that.

Comment: When the player chooses 1, 2, or 3 you don't actually save that choice anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

This is one way to make it loop:

```
string playerChoice = "";
Console.Write("Do you want to play rock, paper, scissors? ");
playerChoice = Console.ReadLine();

while(playerChoice.ToUpper().Trim() == "YES")
{
   Random r = new Random();
   int computerChoice = r.Next(1, 4);

   // Put the rest of the code to figure results of game here



   Console.Write("Do you want to play rock, paper, scissors? ");
   playerChoice = Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues with your program that I will try and walk though with you.

1. You ask if the player wants to play, if the player types "yes", you go into a do/while loop.  Your program will stay in the do/while loop forever because you never ask the player if he wants to play again, so the answer is always "YES".
2. You are reusing your `playerChoice` variable both for if the player wants to play the game AND if they are choosing paper, rock or scissor once the game starts.  These should be two probably should be different variables.
3. You are never storing the result of the players paper, rock, scissor choice.  This is a combination of issue #2 in that you are comparing "YES" to 1, 2 or 3 in the switch statements.

To resolve issue #1, you should reask if the player would like to play again at the end of the loop logic so that you get a new YES/NO input from the user.

```
   Console.Write("Do you want to play rock, paper, scissors? ");
   playerChoice = Console.ReadLine().ToUpper();
   } while (playerChoice == "YES");
 }
}
```

To resolve issues #2 and #3, you should use a new variable to hold the user's choice of paper, rock, scissor.

```
Console.Write("Do you want to play rock, paper, scissors? ");
string playerChoice = Console.ReadLine();
playerChoice = playerChoice.ToUpper();


Random r = new Random();
int computerChoice = r.Next(1, 4);

//new variable for holding the player's input for rock/paper/scissor
string playerThrowChoice;
do
{
    if (computerChoice == 1)
    {
      Console.WriteLine("Computer chose Rock");
      Console.Write("Player choice: type 1, 2, or 3 (1=rock 2=paper 3=scissors): ");
      playerThrowChoice = Console.ReadKey();

     //beginning of switch
     //notice we are using our new variable here
     switch (playerThrowChoice )
     {
         case "1":
             Console.WriteLine("/nIt is a tie!");
             break;
         case "2":
             Console.WriteLine("/nYou win! Paper covers rock!");
             break;
         case "3":
             Console.WriteLine("/nComputer wins! Rock crushes scissors!");
             break;
         }//end of switch
 }

/// ....the rest of your logic
```

Comment: One additional thing I will leave for you to figure out....you are telling the user what the computer picked before you ask them what they want to pick :)  How do you think you could modify your code so that the user does not know what the computer picked before making a selection?